# switch camera during call peer js webrtc?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

we are using peer js webrtc for video call. Everything is working fine just the problem is i am not able to switch camera during call. I have done some work where i can switch camera in local during call but its doesnt effect on remote area.

here is my code

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
     
        var valueSelected = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
        alert(valueSelected);
        //var myselect = 0;

        if (valueSelected == "0") {
            var cameras = [];
            devices.forEach(function (device) {
                'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId);
            });
            var constraints = { video: { deviceId: { exact: cameras[0] } } };

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
             

              
                    window.localStream = stream;
                
                myapp.setMyVideo(window.localStream)
              
                //if (callback)
                //    callback();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
                alert('Unable to call ' + err.name)
            });
        }
        else {
            var cameras = [];
            devices.forEach(function (device) {
                'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId);
            });
            var constraints = { video: { deviceId: { exact: cameras[1] } } };

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
              

            
                    window.localStream = stream;
               

                myapp.setMyVideo(window.localStream)
                //if (callback)
                //    callback();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
                alert('Unable to call ' + err.name)
            });
        }
        //var myselect = $("#myselect option:selected").val();

       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to change stream when a peer-to-peer connection is established is to use *replaceTrack* function that does not require ICE renegotiation:
[RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack)

The documentation says:

> Among the use cases for replaceTrack() is the common need to switch between the rear- and front-facing cameras on a phone. With replaceTrack(), you can simply have a track object for each camera and switch between the two as needed. See the example...